# Implementing Q/A scenario with Graph Database

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, titan

I wanted to know that am I implementing a Graph DB scanerio correct or not. I am trying with `Titan Graph Database` and `neo4j`

`user-1` has asked a question `this is question1` to `user-2`

`user-2` replied to that question

`user-3` also replied to that question

Here is the picture How i am doing this. Am i doing it correct or there is some space of improvement??

[image]
I want following query answer from this picture:

- Question asked by a user
- Question asked to a user
- All reply to a question.
- Who replied to a question (here is my doubt with the above picture because I dont have direct connection to user who replied. One solution that I am thinking will be a edge from user vertex to question vertex but i am not sure is it efficient or not)

Comment: I think i am going right after seeing this http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-J0yE-6wPAbY/URJVjDO9ETI/AAAAAAAAI28/BTuJDJw5uWA/s1600/SIB+schema+v1.jpeg

Answer (score 3):

I think your model is sensible

I show some sample Neo4j Cypher statements for your questions:

Questions asked by a user

```
MATCH (u:User {name:{name}})-[:ASKED]->(q:Question) RETURN q
```

Question asked to a user

```
MATCH (u:User {name:{name}})<-[:ASKEDTO]-(q:Question) RETURN q
```

All reply to a question.

```
MATCH (a:Answer)<-[:REPLYTO]->(q:Question {id:{question}) RETURN a
```

Who replied to a question

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:REPLY]->(a:Answer)<-[:REPLYTO]->(:Question {id:{question}) RETURN a,u
```

Feel free to check out the Neo4j [online course](http://neo4j.org/learn/online_course) for details.